# Security concerns over ˆf_bisa label showing up on Gmail

Tags: gmail

Gmail started showing an unidentified label/folder `ˆf_bisa`.
Doing a quick check, I see that this has only surfaced within the last couple of days:

[image]

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/120772882/strange-label-keeps-appearing
https://support.google.com/mail/thread/120824491/gmail-making-a-label-by-itself-how-to-stop
https://www.tnwcreations.com/post/what-is-f_bisa-gmail-tag-suddenly-appearing/

I've not used any sidekick nor any email tracking services, so I'm curious why this was appearing for me, and more importantly any security concerns - i.e. who was making unauthorised read/changes on my inbox.

And if I were not the one using the service, does it mean someone else who was had access to my inbox?

[image]
(ss from https://piunikaweb.com/2021/08/14/gmail-f_bisa-label-keeps-showing-up-even-after-deleting-for-many/)

[image]
(ss from https://www.andyparkhill.co.uk/2021/08/)

Any insights or if anyone did dig deeper? The explanations are always going to be attributing to a "bug" or "glitch", but there is a high chance there are some implications involved. ie. why did the hypothetical 3rd party service that I did not subscribe to have access to my inbox?

### Update

There must be commonalities amongst the folks who experienced this. I am attempting to disable permissions/configs setting by setting to see if I can isolate this.

Comment: According to the comments of your first link, it appears it's a bug from Gmail, happening when saving a draft. There are no reasons to believe this can result in a security issue.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of a 3rd party with access? You are asking about "implications" but have not defined what the actual event is. Without something specific, the only thing anyone can do is speculate.

Comment: that's based on the comments on forums that people have attributed to. My post asks about findings, and if I have evidence of 3rd party access, why would I need to ask this question in the first place?

Comment: I'm not trying to be unkind. I'm asking if you are seeing 3rd party access. If not, then we are only speculating both what the implications are, and what the implications are for *you*.

Comment: This appears to be an evolving issue with more info coming. Until facts are known, we can only guess, and then when facts come, all we are going to be able to do is to point you to the links with the facts.

Comment: some tact and graciousness in tone would go a long way. symptoms are observed and have been stated. questioning for root cause or evidence is non-value adding regardless of how much reputation one has.